# Add image on home page in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, app-builder, lightning-home-page

I have custom home page. I want to add image on home page which is basically a company logo.

I have tried following things.
 1. Add HTML in rich text: We can add a field called rich text on home page. But problem here is we can not add an Image. Also I tried to add HTML in this field but HTML is rendered as text.
 2. I have created a custom VF page and added an image in it. But here the problem is we are getting title before logo which looks ugly and does not give a look and feel of a logo.

Can I remove the heading or add CSS or Script which will give look and feel of a logo. I tried it but not able to do so.
Or is their any another way to add an image on home page.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a visualforce page, use a lightning component that `implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"`, so it is available on the App Builder. For example:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <img src="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman/batman-logo-big.gif" width="150"/>
</aura:component>
```

Can be add to the page layout and becomes this:

[image]